# Can we update roles in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I can setup roles in Elasticsearch , but I want to update privilege on one of my index for a specific role. Can we update role or we have to set new rule. If we have to set new rule then, how can we update existing user for that role

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,all I had to do was send PUT request. I was sending POST request

```
curl -u elastic -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/role/main_role?pretty' -d ' {"indices" :[{ "names" : ["*"], "privileges" : ["read"] }]}'
```

first the privileges was `read` I changed to `write`